# How to use (import (prefix ...))

Tags: namespaces, chicken-scheme

I'm trying to figure out how to use the

```
 > (import (prefix some-module :some-module))
```

docs are [here](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Modules#prefix)

I found the example of the definition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28860140/59439).

Now, how do I then refer to a definition on it?

Here are some things I tried:

`:some-module.baz`
`some-module.baz`
`:some-module:baz`
`some-module:baz`

None of them worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an answer in the #chicken irc room.

The example I saw with the colon in front of the prefix is wrong.  It should be:

```
> (import (prefix some-module some-module:))
```

Then to use:

```
> (some-module:baz)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the documentation you link to is for the major version 4 of CHICKEN (.../**4**/Modules), which is very old and at this point it can be considered obsolete.  If you are using CHICKEN 5 (hopefully), the documentation is [here](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/5/Modules#rename) (note the **5** in the URL).  `use` is for CHICKEN 4 only.  In CHICKEN 5 you should use `import`.